# How to handle large amount of HTML in a javascript library

Tags: javascript, html

I was tasked to create a javascript library.
The role of this library is to create a complex form with multiple choices/steps on any website. (It means that we don't have access to the website where the form is deployed.)

The code to use the library is the following :

```
<body>
    <div id="container"><!-- Here should be inserted my HTML form --></div>
</body>
<script src="http://wwww.example.com/path/to/myLibrary.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        var dom = document.getElementById('container');
        var mb = new MLibrary(dom);
        mb.initialize();
    })();
</script>
```

Once filled, this form is finally sent to our API endpoint where it is treated.
Because of the complexity of the form, I need to create a huge amount of element using javascript. The HTML source code of the form is ~600 lines of HTML
Having this much HTML inside a .js file has proved to be ridiculously hard to maintain and horrible to read.
Because of performance purpose, I was required to avoid AJAX request as much as possible which means that I should avoid to store the HTML on the server and get it through AJAX.

---

**If you can't use AJAX to get HTML, how can you handle a large amount of HTML inside a javascript library in order for it to be maintainable ?**

I've created a very basic version of this library using JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/xd4ojka2/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem awhile back. Basically, I had to bundle my html with my js with [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). In development, all code lives in it's own file: html inside `.html`, js in `.js`, less or sass in their respective files. Then Webpack will build the app by combining all these files, giving me a `build.js` file (the name is configurable).

That file might be bigger than your average JS file, but it has all the stuff your app needs, meaning no AJAX to fetch HTML, or other parts of the app. Since this file will be kept in browser's cache, you need to implement a cache busting (outside of the scope of this question).

Answer (score -1):

You could programmatically create HTML tags using JSON input on the fly. The JSON input for generating the markup can be retrieved using AJAX calls or stored in LocalStorage on app initialization or be lazy loaded.